# Bootstrap table with fixed column and col span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I found one sample that is working with row span, and fixed first few columns in bootstrap table.
I tried to modify it to col span but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to work with col span and fixed columns
in bootstrap table. Thanks.

Here is the sample:
[Jsfiddle row span and fixed columns](https://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/3v7h5erL/3/)

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-fixed-columns="true" data-fixed-number="3">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th colspan='2'>1</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>4</th>
  <th>5</th>
  <th>6</th>
  <th>7</th>
  <th>8</th>
  <th>9</th>
  <th>10</th>
  <th>11</th>
  <th>12</th>
  <th>13</th>
  <th>14</th>
  <th>15</th>
  <th>16</th>
  <th>16</th>
  <th>17</th>
  <th>18</th>
  <th>19</th>
  <th>20</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">Momentum</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">Best EPS</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. do you want to recreate the sample fiddle?

Comment: @H.Brendan i try to modify the sample to support col span with fixed columns. If you can provide some sample also can.

Comment: i tried something out paste the TD's in the fiddle and try it out im not sure if this is what you wanted,

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is this.

```
<td rowspan="3">Momentum</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td  colspan="2">3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td> Delete this one.
```

this would just return something like al boxes only one is then just 2 width.

Comment: I want when scrolling the first column is fixed.

Comment: position: fixed; add this to the first column then